# Stream computer camera on blazor WASM website and receive each display image

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I have two problems which I need to solve in my blazor app. What I'm trying to achieve in the end is to decode barcodes from a computer camera and the user should be able to see the camera stream while it is trying to find a barcode.

Decoding the barcodes isn't much of a problem, I just stated this to give some background to my question. There are two problems atm:

1. Display computer camera image stream in blazor app
2. Receive each of the displayed images in a method (while the stream is running)

When searching for a way I later found this NuGet package: https://github.com/Mercurial/BlazorMedia

But it is very complicated. I tried using it and it finally showed a stream:

```
<VideoMedia OnData="GotData"></VideoMedia>

@code 
{
    private void GotData(byte[] bytes)
    {

    }
}
```

But when I looked at the bytes and also converted them into a string, it didn't seem like I got data for any image. Normally such a bitmap would have some data at the start stating what kind of image it is, but with all attempts to decode this image, I got nothing working in the end.

Maybe I'm using this component wrong or I'm missing something else. The stream works perfectly find, but I still need to receive the frames to decode barcodes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've got exactly what you need. A while back I wrote a blazor component library that can stream a camera video and fires an event on each frame it receives because I didn't find any component allowing this:

[BlazorCameraStreamer](https://github.com/baltermia/blazor-camera-streamer)

It's pretty simple to use, you can read the docs on the GitHub page, but I'll sum it up here really quick:

1. First install the NuGet package of course.
2. Then add the following script tag either in your `wwwroot\index.html` (wasm) or `Pages\_Host.cshtml` (serverside) file, depending on your blazor project type (you didn't specify it in your question).

```html
<script src="_content/BlazorCameraStreamer/js/CameraStreamer.js"></script>
```

3. Add the `@using BlazorCameraStreamer` in your `_Imports.razor` file
4. Then add the component in your razor code:

```html
<CameraStreamer Autostart OnFrame=OnFrameHandler />
```

And the handler method in your C# code:

```cs
private void OnFrameHandler(string data)
{
    // image is saved as a base64 string (you might want to convert this to a byte[]/bitmap)
}
```

This is the most minimal implementation of the component. It will ask the user for camera permission and then display the video. The `OnFrameHandler` will be called on each new frame with an image.

The component allows a lot more configuration of itself (requesting camera access, starting/stopping stream etc.), if you need it, check out the GitHub documentation.

---

For your barcode decoding concern, I've also got you covered:

[BarcodeStreamer.ImageSharp](https://github.com/baltermia/barcodereader-imagesharp)

I wrote both of these components to decode barcodes on a website in blazor, so pretty much everything you need.

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I needed thank you! I tried it in the blazor app and it worked without much configuration :)

Comment: Might be a long shot, but I just came across this and trying to do the same thing, but am getting huge memory leaks, is the right way to do this to process the frame with the barcode in the `OnFrameHandler` method?

Comment: @EyeSeeSharp that could be possible, although I haven't noticed that yet myself (haven't worked on the project in a while tho). If memory leaks are occurring for you, you can happily create an issue in the repo so I can take a better look into the issue.

Comment: @baltermia thanks for the reply- I just replied to another issue there that's more pressing for me, being able to default to rear camera on mobile device, hoping you can assist!